# Selected button by user resets to default after switching to another window in Pygame

Tags: python, function, pygame

I've been trying to create a simple game using PyGame. There is an option in the game for the user to customize their board color into one of the six possible colors available in the game. So basically if the user clicks on the chessboard icon, a new window opens which lets them choose a color they prefer for their board, like so:

[image: board]

By clicking on the first icon with the chessboard image, the options windows opens:

[image: options]

As you can see, the default board is set to green (as expected), now image the user wants to have a blue board, so they click on the button on which is written "BLUE".
The result goes like this:

[image: newboard]

Now, as expected, we have a blue board. Now let's say the user doesn't like it blue and decides to **AGAIN** choose another board color, so they open the options window again:

[image: optionswin]

Look what just happened, the selected button is set to the default "GREEN" again, although the user had chosen "BLUE" last time.

How can I fix this problem and make it not set to default again?
Here are the snippets of my code that corresponds to the above functionality:

```
def board_color_select(board_default=0, piece_default='pawn', pos=(336, 252)):
    bg = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/ffcba4.png')
    return_button = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-reply-arrow-64(1).png')
    grey_mode_button = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Desktop/CGB02-grey_M_btn.png')
    green_mode_button = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Desktop/CGB02-green_M_btn.png')

    green_font = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629543607354.png')
    grey_font = pygame.image. load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629543845773.png')
    pink_font = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629544089972.png')
    blue_font = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629544268459.png')
    purple_font = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629544429630.png')
    red_font = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629544606588.png')
    board_font = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629544715543.png')

    pygame.init()

    root = pygame.display.set_mode((672, 672))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Board Design')
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 55)
    textsurface = font.render("BOARD", False, (255, 255, 255))
    mode_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 25)

    mode_one_surface = mode_font.render("GREEN", False, (255, 255, 255))
    mode_two_surface = mode_font.render("BLUE", False, (255, 255, 255))
    mode_three_surface = mode_font.render("PINK", False, (255, 255, 255))
    mode_four_surface = mode_font.render("GREY", False, (255, 255, 255))
    mode_five_surface = mode_font.render("RED", False, (255, 255, 255))
    mode_six_surface = mode_font.render("PURPLE", False, (255, 255, 255))

    run = True

    #default = 0
    
    while run:
        root.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        root.blit(board_font, (229, 30))
        root.blit(return_button, (7, 7))

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        mode_one_button_collide = pygame.Rect(50, 150, 256, 140)
        mode_two_button_collide = pygame.Rect(50, 320, 256, 140)
        mode_three_button_collide = pygame.Rect(50, 490, 256, 140)
        mode_four_button_collide = pygame.Rect(366, 150, 256, 140)
        mode_five_button_collide = pygame.Rect(366, 320, 256, 140)
        mode_six_button_collide = pygame.Rect(366, 490, 256, 140)
        return_button_collide = pygame.Rect(7, 7, 50, 50)

        if mode_two_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                board_default = 1 #mode 2
                
        elif  mode_one_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                board_default = 6 #mode 1

        elif mode_three_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                board_default = 2 #mode 3

        elif mode_four_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                board_default = 3 #mode 4
        elif mode_five_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                board_default = 4 #mode 5
        elif mode_six_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                board_default = 5 #mode 6
        elif return_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                game(board_default, piece_default, pos)

        if board_default == 1: #if mode 1 is selected
            root.blit(green_mode_button, (50, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 490))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 490))
            game(board_default, piece_default, pos)

        elif board_default == 0:
            root.blit(green_mode_button, (50, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 490))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 490))
            
        elif board_default == 2:
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 320))
            root.blit(green_mode_button, (50, 490))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 490))
            game(board_default, piece_default, pos)

        elif board_default == 3:
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 490))
            root.blit(green_mode_button, (366, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 490))
            game(board_default, piece_default, pos)

        elif board_default == 4:
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 490))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 150))
            root.blit(green_mode_button, (366, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 490))
            game(board_default, piece_default, pos)

        elif board_default == 5:
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 490))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 320))
            root.blit(green_mode_button, (366, 490))
            game(board_default, piece_default, pos)

        elif board_default == 6:
            root.blit(green_mode_button, (50, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (50, 490))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 150))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 320))
            root.blit(grey_mode_button, (366, 490))
            game(0, piece_default, pos)

        root.blit(green_font, (84, 187.5))
        root.blit(grey_font, (99, 357.5))
        root.blit(pink_font, (102, 527.5))
        root.blit(blue_font, (416, 187.5))
        root.blit(purple_font, (382.5, 357.5))
        root.blit(red_font, (430, 527.5))
        
        click = False

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True

        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()

def game(default_board=0, default_piece='pawn', pos=(336, 252)):
    purple_board = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/checkerboard_purple(1).png')
    red_board = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/checkerboard_red(1).png')
    pink_board = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/checkerboard_pink(1).png')
    green_board = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/checkerboard_green(2).png')
    blue_board = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/checkerboard_blue(1).png')
    grey_board = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Desktop/chessboard.gif')

    green_bg = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/80bd8f.png')
    blue_bg = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/2ca7b9.png')
    pink_bg = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/d394bb.png')
    red_bg = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/e4746b.png')
    purple_bg = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/9394cc.png')
    grey_bg = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/d7ded3.png') 

    return_icon = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-reply-arrow-50(3).png')
    exit_icon = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-close-window-50.png')

    chessboard_icon_green = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-chess-board-50.png')
    chesspiece_icon_green = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-board-game-figure-50.png')
    mute_icon_green = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-mute-50(3).png')
    position_icon_green = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-place-marker-50.png')

    chessboard_icon_black = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-chess-board-50(2).png')
    chesspiece_icon_black = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-board-game-figure-50(1).png')
    mute_icon_black = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-mute-50(2).png')
    position_icon_black = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-place-marker-50(2).png')

    chessboard_icon_blue = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-chess-board-50(3).png')
    chesspiece_icon_blue = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-board-game-figure-50(2).png')
    mute_icon_blue = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-mute-50(4).png')
    position_icon_blue = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-place-marker-50(3).png')

    chessboard_icon_red = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-chess-board-50(1).png')
    chesspiece_icon_red = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-board-game-figure-50(3).png')
    mute_icon_red = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-mute-50(5).png')
    position_icon_red = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-place-marker-50(4).png')

    chessboard_icon_purple = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-chess-board-50(5).png')
    chesspiece_icon_purple = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-board-game-figure-50(4).png')
    mute_icon_purple = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-mute-50(6).png')
    position_icon_purple = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-place-marker-50(5).png')

    chessboard_icon_pink = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-chess-board-50(6).png')
    chesspiece_icon_pink = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-board-game-figure-50(5).png')
    mute_icon_pink = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-mute-50(7).png')
    position_icon_pink = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-place-marker-50(6).png')

    chessboard_hover = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629794955368.png')
    chesspiece_hover = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629795041496.png')
    mute_hover = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629795088276.png')
    position_hover = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629795118799.png')
    return_hover = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629795781903.png')
    exit_hover = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/text-1629795796445.png')

    player_king = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-king-80(4).png')
    player_queen = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-queen-80(2).png')
    player_knight = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-knight-80(11).png')
    player_rook = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-rook-80(2).png')
    player_pawn = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-pawn-80(2).png')
    player_bishop = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-bishop-80(2).png')

    possible = pygame.image.load('/home/liana/Downloads/icons8-square-84(1).png')

    pygame.init()

    root = pygame.display.set_mode((730, 730))

    pygame.display.set_caption('Chess')
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 45)
    textsurface = font.render("CONTROLS", False, (255, 255, 255))

    run = True

    board_color = green_board
    bg_color = green_bg
    chessboard_default_icon = chessboard_icon_green
    chesspiece_default_icon = chesspiece_icon_green
    mute_default_icon = mute_icon_green
    position_default_icon = position_icon_green

    while run:
        if default_board == 0:
            board_color = green_board
            bg_color = green_bg
            chessboard_default_icon = chessboard_icon_green
            chesspiece_default_icon = chesspiece_icon_green
            mute_default_icon = mute_icon_green
            position_default_icon = position_icon_green

        elif default_board == 1:
            board_color = grey_board
            bg_color = grey_bg
            chessboard_default_icon = chessboard_icon_black
            chesspiece_default_icon = chesspiece_icon_black
            mute_default_icon = mute_icon_black
            position_default_icon = position_icon_black

        elif default_board == 2:
            board_color = pink_board
            bg_color = pink_bg
            chessboard_default_icon = chessboard_icon_pink
            chesspiece_default_icon = chesspiece_icon_pink
            mute_default_icon = mute_icon_pink
            position_default_icon = position_icon_pink

        elif default_board == 3:
            board_color = blue_board
            bg_color = blue_bg
            chessboard_default_icon = chessboard_icon_blue
            chesspiece_default_icon = chesspiece_icon_blue
            mute_default_icon = mute_icon_blue
            position_default_icon = position_icon_blue

        elif default_board == 4:
            board_color = purple_board
            bg_color = purple_bg
            chessboard_default_icon = chessboard_icon_purple
            chesspiece_default_icon = chesspiece_icon_purple
            mute_default_icon = mute_icon_purple
            position_default_icon = position_icon_purple

        elif default_board == 5:
            board_color = red_board
            bg_color = red_bg
            chessboard_default_icon = chessboard_icon_red
            chesspiece_default_icon = chesspiece_icon_red
            mute_default_icon = mute_icon_red
            position_default_icon = position_icon_red

        root.blit(bg_color, (0, 0))
        root.blit(board_color, (0, 0))
        root.blit(chessboard_default_icon, (677, 4))
        root.blit(chesspiece_default_icon, (677, 68))
        root.blit(mute_default_icon, (677, 133))
        root.blit(position_default_icon, (677, 197))
        root.blit(return_icon, (677, 261))
        root.blit(exit_icon, (677, 325))

        if default_piece == 'pawn':
            root.blit(player_pawn, pos)
        elif default_piece == 'knight':
            root.blit(player_knight, pos)
        elif default_piece == 'rook':
            root.blit(player_rook, pos)
        elif default_piece == 'queen':
            root.blit(player_queen, pos)
        elif default_piece == 'king':
            root.blit(player_king, pos)
        elif default_piece == 'bishop':
            root.blit(player_bishop, pos)

        possible_area = show_possible(default_piece, pos)

        #print(f'POSSIBLE AREA: {possible_area}')

        for i in possible_area:
        #rect_pos = pygame.Rect(tuple(i))
        #pygame.draw.rect(win, (230, 0, 115), rect_pos)
            root.blit(possible, i)
        
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        chessboard_icon_collide = pygame.Rect(677, 4, 50, 50)
        exit_button_collide = pygame.Rect(677, 325, 50, 50)
        return_button_collide = pygame.Rect(677, 261, 50, 50)
        piece_icon_collide = pygame.Rect(677, 68, 50, 50)
        mute_icon_collide = pygame.Rect(677, 132, 50, 50)
        position_icon_collide = pygame.Rect(677, 196, 50, 50)

    
        if chessboard_icon_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            root.blit(chessboard_hover, (573, 21))
            if click:
                board_color_select(0, default_piece, pos)

        elif piece_icon_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            root.blit(chesspiece_hover, (548, 85))
            if click:
                piece_choose(default_board, default_piece, pos)

        elif mute_icon_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            root.blit(mute_hover, (573, 149))

        elif position_icon_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            root.blit(position_hover, (537, 213))
            if click:
                set_pos(board_color, bg_color, default_piece, default_board)

        elif return_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            root.blit(return_hover, (511, 277))

        elif exit_button_collide.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            root.blit(exit_hover, (573, 341))
            if click:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        click = False
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True

        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()

game()
```

I really appreciate any help in advance. Any tips, brief explanation of what I'm supposed to do or solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `board_color_select` with `default_board` instead of 0.

<s>`board_color_select(0, default_piece, pos)`</s>

```py
board_color_select(default_board, default_piece, pos)
```

Comment: When I do that I get such an error: ``` File "/home/liana/Desktop/check.py", line 594, in game
    if click:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'click' referenced before assignment```

Comment: @Mania Please note that I cannot debug your code. I can just spot the obvious bug.